# Did any metal airplane use a Maxwell slot?

Tags: aviation-history, high-lift-device

The Douglas DC-8 used leading-edge slots. Unlike slots in light planes, [this one was door operated](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/84598/14897).

I thought Douglas must have patented it. But as far as I searched, they did not. So it must have been an older design. More researching later, I arrived at a patent, inconveniently titled "[Airplane wing](https://patents.google.com/patent/US2381678A/en)", by Frank R Maxwell *(image below).* Which is the same as the DC-8 minus the pop-out upper part. Earlier designs by Maxwell for this design date back to at least 1928.

And indeed a 1937 NACA report, *[Wind-tunnel tests of a Clark Y wing with 'Maxwell' leading-edge slots](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19930081343),* uses the term **Maxwell slot** to describe them.

> For a given slat size the Maxwell wing with the narrow slat has approximately the same aerodynamic characteristics as the Handley Page type of slotted wing.

Did any metal airplane use a true Maxwell slot? One example would suffice. I haven't been able to find any. I *think* the 'pop-up part' is important; the DC-8-style slot did not work on the DC-9 without vortilons (during development).

[image]

Comment: Was it used more on non-metal planes? Are there any disadvantages to Maxwell slots, since there were apparently so few planes equipped with them?

Comment: @DohnJoe: doubt there are non-metal examples since it needs thickness, performance wise as quoted it's similar to the popular alternative, and actually mechanically simpler as well -- why it isn't popular I don't know, I only found about them like a week ago

Answer (score 5):

***Finally!*** The **[Vought OS2U Kingfisher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vought_OS2U_Kingfisher)** (first flight 1938). At least the OS2U-2 model...

> **Production variant** with minor equipment changes and powered by a 450 hp (336 kW) Pratt & Whitney R-985-50, 158 built. [emphasis mine]

... had default Maxwell slots, thanks to a wartime NACA report.<sup>[1]</sup> The report makes no mention of the plane's model, but another report does in the references section.<sup>[2]</sup>

I thought, it can't be true, it must have been a NACA modification. But no, the first reference explicitly lists the modifications done. The first of which is what I needed:

> Modification 1.– Auxiliary slats were mounted ahead and above the normal leading edge of the wing root, overlapping the inboard end of the **original Maxwell slot arrangement** by about an inch (fig. 11). [happy-emphasis mine]

And that's not all. The PDF is a 90 MB color scan, so, photos, naturally:

[image]

Photos are hard to come by, but I found one that shows the popped-up leading-edge from behind:

> [image]
> Source: [ww2db.com](https://ww2db.com/image.php?image_id=23497); the plane was available in land/sea configurations.

---

1: Adams, Betty. "Flight Measurements of the Effects of a Wing Leading-edge Slot and Other Modifications on the Stability, Maximum Lift, and High Speed of an Observation Airplane." (1943). https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19930093568

2: Adams, Betty. "Flight measurements of the effect of various amounts of aileron droop on the low-speed lateral-control characteristics of an observation airplane." (1943). https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19930092611